# Running my Puppeteer app within PM2's cluster mode doesn't take advantage of the multiple processes

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pm2

While running my Puppeteer app with PM2's cluster mode enabled, during concurrent requests, only one of the processes seems to be utilized instead of all 4 (1 for each of my cores). Here's the basic flow of my program:

```
helpers.startChrome()
.then((resp) => {
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
         const {webSocketUrl} = JSON.parse(resp.body);
         let browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: webSocketUrl}); 
         const page = await browser.newPage();

         ... //do puppeteer stuff

         await page.close();
         await browser.disconnect();
    })
})
```

and here is the startChrome() function:

```
    startChrome: function(){
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const opts = {
                //chromeFlags: ["--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--use-gl=egl"],
                userDataDir: "D:/pupeteercache",
                output: 'json'
            };

            // Launch chrome using chrome-launcher.
            const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch(opts);
            opts.port = chrome.port;

            // Connect to it using puppeteer.connect().
            resp = await util.promisify(request)(`http://localhost:${opts.port}/json/version`);
            resolve(resp);
        })
    }
```

First, I use a package called chrome-launcher to start up chrome, I then setup a simple http server that listens for incoming requests to my app. When a request is recieved, i connect to the chrome endpoint i setup through chrome-launcher at the beginning.

When i now try to run this app within PM2's cluster mode, 4 separate chrome tabs are opened up (not sure why it works this way but alright), and everything seems to be running fine. But when I send the server 10 concurrent requests to test and see if all processes are getting used, only the first one is. I know this because when i run `PM2 monit`, only the first process is using any memory.

Can someone explain to me why all the processes aren't utilized? Is it because of how i'm using chrome-launcher to only use one browser with multiple tabs instead of running multiple browsers?

Comment: What does your "helpers.startChrome" function do? Does it actually start a new chrome process?

Comment: @laggingreflex sorry i should've included that code in the question, i have edited my post. But yeah, it _should_ start up a new chrome process everytime it's executed, but right now, when it's running with PM2's cluster mode, it only seems to be starting 1 chrome process with 4 tabs. I expected it to start up a new chrome browser each time at a different port, but with cluster mode enabled for PM2, it does not.

Comment: Remove the "userDataDir" line and then see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the same user directory for multiple instances at same time. If you pass a user directory, no matter what kind of launcher it is, it will automatically pick the running process and create a new tab on that instead.

Puppeteer creates a temporary profile whenever you want to launch the browser. So if you want to utilize 4 instances, pass it a different user data directory on each instance.

Comment: Huh, ok yeah that fixed it. I would never have guessed that setting that parameter would have been the issue